# How do I find the SQL query behind an Oracle Apex form/page?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I'm on version 23.2.1 and just getting started with SQL. I've created a number of pages using Apex but I can't find the SQL queries I originally used to create them. I've looked everywhere and I can't find them. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query `APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_REGIONS` and check its `REGION_SOURCE` column.

On the other hand, why don't you navigate to that page and literally check its source?